# What is the difference between control+M character and a '\r' character. And how do we write it?

Tags: algorithm, unix, awk, ksh, gawk

What is the difference between `'control+M'` character and a `'\r'` character.

Both are not the same. How do we write control+M character in gawk like we write '\r'.

My aim is to tell gawk, take 'comtrol+M' character as RS(record separator).

for '\r'  we can write as

```
gawk -v RS='\r' 'code goes here' file

gawk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\n' '{gsub(/\n/,"",$0)} {print $0}' rawfile > newfile_slashr_removed
```

Here instead of `'\r'` I want to take `'comtrol+M'`

Background:

```
$ grep '\r' raw_file | wc
   1468   44570 2641642

$ grep '^M' raw_file | wc
   1463   44522 2638958
```

After I use the above code and take the output and put it in the file,

```
$ grep  '^M' WDY_worker_incr_newfile | wc
      0       0       0
$ grep '\r' WDY_worker_incr_newfile | wc
   1464   44570 2640175
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `printf "^M" | od` prints the same as `printf "\r" | od`. Maybe use `grep -c` rather than `grep ... | wc`

Comment: Why do you think that control-M and `\r` are different?

Comment: Henry, I have shown you the results of grep command on the same file. The result is different.

Comment: Are you sure that `grep '^M'` does not mach lines starting with `M`?

Comment: `\r`'s decimal value is 13 (`man ascii`) and just as it happens `M` is the 13th letter.

Comment: @Henry, Yes, I'm sure. I am writing 'control+v+m' while greping.. it gives the exact number of control+m characters but '\r' seems to be different. '\r'seems to be '\n' character or a control+M char.

Comment: You are now contradicting yourself. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You do not write `^M`, you press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and *then* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> key combinations. The initial Ctrl-V makes the shell command line editing “escape” the next key — ordinarily, Ctrl-M will be mapped to the same action as Return in your shell, but with this, you can type a literal Carriage Return on the command line.

With this, you can then write `RS='^M'` and `grep '^M'` by typing `RS='` + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> + `'` etc.

On a modern shell (mksh, AT&T ksh93, GNU bash, etc.), you can also write `RS=$'\r'` and `grep $'\r'` instead, the dollar-apostrophe quote interpolates C-style escape sequences.

Most tools *do not* allow you to just write `'\r'`; printf and tr are exceptions, and there may or may not be others, depending on the operating system and tools used (e.g. GNU sed allows them in more places than BSD sed).

You tagged this as `unix`, but, just as another point of caution, on DOS-based environments like Cygwin32, `^M^J` is the line separator, not just `^J` like on proper Unix, so tools may misbehave if you want to re-use the Carriage Return.